# Statement cannot resolve address of overloaded function C++ indicators

Tags: c++

Statement cannot resolve address of overloaded function.

I try to learn indicators in C++, how to make it work?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int XD = 330;
int *iks;



int main()
{
    iks = &XD;
    cout << "Hello" << endl;
    cout <<  iks;   << endl;
    cout << *iks;   << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What couldn't be resolved actually?

Comment: 13 and 14 line of code

Comment: You don't provide any line numbers. Just highlight using comment in yous sample.

Comment: Probably has to do with the semicolons in the `cout` expression. Remove those.

Comment: Don't put `;` randomly in your code!

Answer (score 2):

You have unnecessary semicolon in lines 13 & 14, should be:

```
cout <<  iks   << endl;
cout << *iks   << endl;
```

And, by the way, the thing you call *indicators* are really called *pointers* in English.